# Cefsharp WPF combobox rendering issue

Tags: wpf, windows, combobox, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

In some devices CefShapr WPF example 1.25.7 (cef1) has strange issue. CefSharp render comboboxes in the wrong place like with render TranslateTransform. All devices have same DPI 96 and screen resolution.

What could be the reason for this issue? Thanks.

[Issue Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c6le7g8klg6lk41/cefsharp%20rendering%20issue.png). [Normal Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ut9sdm68luleles/cefsharp%20normal.png)

Answer (score 2):

The reason *could* be related to this issue reported in the CEF project http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/issues/detail?id=1208&q=combobox

Maybe you can narrow it further down by checking if it is reproducible with the cefclient.exe which is available as part of the binary downloads for CEF. Also it would be good to know if you can reproduce it with CefSharp3 and/or the CEF3 cefclient.exe - because CEF1 is not maintained anymore.

Please report relevant results found on either CEF3 or CefSharp3 to the appropriate project.

**Update** @Ktulh yes 31.0.0-pre1 doesn't work for me either at https://kontur.ru/ubrir?type=order but with https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/337 it looks like it shows up in the right position - even the first time - at least on my PC. You have to do a build-from-source if you can't wait for the next release due in about a month.

Comment: cefclient.exe has stopped working after pressing combobox.
[link1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60366733/proc.png)
[link2](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60366733/stack.png)

Comment: If the "link1" and "link2" screenshots above are from running a nightly build 3.1921.1661.0 version of `cefclient.exe` downloaded from http://cefbuilds.com then you have found a problem that you must report to the CEF project or discuss in the CEF Forum. Also I think you should check with the latest official release 3.1650 from www.magpcss.net/cef_downloads/

Comment: The current build of CefSharp3 33.0 has this issue.  Apparently the fix was not propagated forward to the newer builds.  Any ideas as who to contact to get a fix for this?

Comment: @CaptainBli as the issue in CEF hasn't been closed yet you currently have to apply the patch to CEF sources, build it. Use CefSharp's cef-binary `build.ps1` to NuGet package it and use it with CefSharp. CefSharp 33 is based on the CEF 1750 branch. CEF development is now at the 2062 branch or newer which will land in CefSharp 37.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a 100% perfect answer, but since [this bug](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/200) has been fixed (= and popups, e.g. comboboxes are now supported with CefSharp3), I believe this problem does not exist with CefSharp3. Could you test it to see? It would be really cool to see if it works correctly for you there.

Please note that this is only valid for the CefSharp3 code from github. The latest binary release does not yet have this fix in it, but hopefully we are not too far away from a new binary release... Any year now. ;)

Comment: CefSharp3 does not work correctly even on my computer. I tried version 31.0.0-pre1.

Comment: 31.0.0 did work for us but there were other reasons we need to move to 33.0.  The current build of CefSharp3 33.0 has this issue. Apparently the fix was not propagated forward to the newer builds. Any ideas as who to contact to get a fix for this?

Comment: @CaptainBli, submit an issue on the GitHub web page for CefSharp. That's the best way to approach it.